# Passing Variable to is_granted in twig (Symfony)

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm having trouble getting the is_granted function in twig to test a variable. In this case, I am testing if the current user is granted the role contained in the form.roles, but unfortunately the is_granted test will ONLY accept a string, and passing a variable is always returning false.

```
                    <div class="form-group well">
            {{ form_label(form.roles) }}
            {% for role in form.roles %}
                {{ role.vars.value|trim }}{% if is_granted('{{ role.vars.value }}') %}
                <div class="row marketing ">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        {{ form_label(role) }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        {{ form_widget(role, {"attr": {"class": "form-control"}} ) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
```

I have tried to filter the output to ensure that it is a string, without success, and the quotes in {% if is_granted('{{ role.vars.value }}') %} MUST be there as the system errors if they are not included.

Output of this code is:

> Allocated Roles ROLE_SYSTEM_ADMIN ROLE_REGISTRAR  ROLE_ADMIN ROLE_PRINCIPAL ROLE_HEAD_TEACHER ROLE_TEACHER ROLE_STUDENT   ROLE_PARENT ROLE_USER

Any idea on how I can get the is_granted to test from the value given?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't open new Twig tags. `{{ ... }}` are for dumping (echoing) and in this case you don't want to echo/dump the content of `role.vars.value`. So change it to: `{% if is_granted(role.vars.value) %}`